# problem with bibtex to cite a web page

Tags: bibtex

i have some problem with bibtex i use to create my bibliography for some site and book

i use latex in overleaf :

for bibfile :

```
@book{wxPython,
    author    = "Rappin, Noel and Robin, Dunn",
    TITLE     = "wxPython in Action ",
    publisher = "Manning Publications",
    YEAR      = "30 mars 2006",
    pages   = "584 ",
    NOTE = "[Consulté le : 16 février 2019]"
    
}
 
@INTERNET{www11b,
    AUTHOR    = "NWCSAF",
      YEAR    = "1997",
      
    TITLE     = "SAF to support to Nowcasting and Very Short Range Forecasting",
    WEBSITE   = "\url{http://www.nwcsaf.org}",
    NOTE = "[Consulté le : 20 février 2019]"
}
```

and

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[nottoc, notlof, notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{ Liste des abréviations}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}

\usepackage{natbib}
\makeglossaries
 
\floatplacement{figure}{H}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\lhead{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0.5pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\today}



\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
\mbox{}
\begin{flushright}
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
\textit{}\\
\vspace{12cm}
\centering 


\chapter*{\centering Remerciements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Remerciements}

\chapter{\centering wxpython}
\chapter{\centering matplotlib }



\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliographie et Webographie}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{bib} 



\newpage
\end{document}
```

when i compil my code i have resultat like :

[image]

for the book all is good but for website no i need to have something like :

```
AUTHOR    = "NWCSAF",
 YEAR    = "1997",
TITLE     = "SAF to support to Nowcasting and Very Short Range Forecasting",
WEBSITE   = "\url{http://www.nwcsaf.org}",
NOTE = "[Consulté le : 20 février 2019]"
```

with year after author

can i use my style for exemple do style with .bst file but how i can do that in latex?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `url` field instead of `website`:

```
url   = {http://www.nwcsaf.org},
```

You don't have to add the `\url{...}` command either, as the `abbrvnat` style will add it for `url` fields.

Comment: @thank you but how i can have the year before TITLE ?

Comment: That depends on the `\bibliographystyle{...}`, so you'll have to experiment with another style.